# Is there a way to color cells if the previous row has the same value in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |

But want this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | in red{3} | 3 |

Can someone help me?

Comment: There isn't quite enough information here to answer this question. Is this inside a jupyter notebook? Also, can you include the code that creates this table, including what libraries you use?

Answer (score 0):

Its in a jupyter notebook, and the code is:

```
    Its in a jupyter notebook, and the code is:

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    df_total = pd.read_excel(...)
    group = df_total.groupby(by="NOME")
    for name, group in group:
       if len(group)>1:
          if name == 'DBS':
             group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
             # row1 = group.iloc[0]
             # row2 = group.iloc[1]
             group.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if 
               x==group.iloc[0,0] else '')
```